# .CORE 5 Web Api and Client MQTT

Tags: c#, mqtt, webapi

is it possible to create a .core webapi project and a mqtt client?
For example, create a separate thread in the startup.cs where you can instantiate a mqtt client

Comment: The server has to start first before you can start the client.  So you want to launch the client after the API is started.

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I try to add a Singleton service to instantiate the mqtt client in startup.cs and it works fine, the program recive  the posted message on topic.
The first question, is it correct to create this service in this location?

The problem is when I try to add the migration or update of the database with the package console tool.
The command does not complete the sequencing and the console is locked.

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer("name=ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"));
            services.AddSingleton<MyMqtt>(new MyMqtt());
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "CoWorkOfficeWebApi", Version = "v1" });
            });
        }
```

Class

```
    public class MyMqtt
    {
        MqttClient client;

        public MyMqtt()
        {
            // create client instance 
            client = new MqttClient("127.0.0.1");
            // register to message received 
            client.MqttMsgPublishReceived += client_MqttMsgPublishReceived;
            string clientId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            client.Connect(clientId);
            // subscribe to the topic "/home/temperature" with QoS 2 
            client.Subscribe(new string[] { "/home/temperature" }, new byte[] { MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE });
        }


        static void client_MqttMsgPublishReceived(object sender, MqttMsgPublishEventArgs e)
        {
            string msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Message);
            Console.WriteLine($"Topic: {e.Topic}, Message: {msg}");
        }
    }
```